# Why does my nfs mount always changes to be owned by root after mounting?

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, nfs

I have a mount point for my nfs share:

```
drwxrwxrwx   2 patryk patryk 4.0K Feb  4 16:23 nfs_share
```

after I mount it I get

```
$ sudo mount -t nfs 10.9.XXX.XXX:/root/src /home/patryk/nfs_share -o rw,user,vers=3 
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root   4.0K Feb  4 17:06 nfs_share
```

I tried with `/etc/fstab` but I get the same results:

```
10.9.XXX.XXX:/root/src /home/patryk/nfs_share nfs rw,user,vers=3 0 0
```

The funny thing is that I cannot `chown` this after mounting:

```
$ sudo chown patryk:patryk nfs_share
chown: changing ownership of `nfs_share': Operation not permitted
```

My server is configured as follows:

```
// 10.9.XXX.XXX
$ cat /etc/exports
/root/src/napet_src/ *(rw,nohide,insecure,no_subtree_check,async)
```

How do I define those permissions so that I can write to this folder?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add uid (user identifier) and guid (group user identifier) like these:

```
$ sudo mount -t nfs 10.9.XXX.XXX:/root/src /home/patryk/nfs_share -o rw,user,vers=3,uid=1001,gid=1001
```

Maybe you need to use id command to find your id/guid:

```
$ id username
```

Although you may use actual user/groupnames (beware of spaces) instead numeric uid, gid values.

Comment: You can also just specify `uid=user,gid=user` and mount will figure out the current user's credentials, if that's what you need.

Comment: For Ubuntu 20.04, the comment above didn't work (the answer did). Error message: "'uid' option needs a decimal value"

Comment: `uid` and `gid` seem to be Windows specific options now.